# How to know when the Stored Procedure Execution Began in SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In profiler it is easy to know when the Stored Procedure Execution Completed using RPC Completed.

Can we know when the Stored Procedure Execution began using Profiler ?

Answer (score -1):

In SQL SERVER Profiler we have a template called T-SQL sps.

We can choose RPC Started Option.